# How to manipulate a RequestHeader in Play2 before the Controller works on it

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.1

I'd like to add a tracingId to trace Requests in Play2 and Services called from within the WebApp.
It should be possible to add the tracingId to the request before the Controller works on the request.

So far I thought this could be accomplished with Filters.

```
object AddTraceIdFilter extends Filter  {
    override def apply(next: (RequestHeader) => Result)(rh: RequestHeader): Result = {

    val traceId = TraceId.fromRequestHeader(rh) getOrElse addAnTraceId
    next(rh).withHeaders( TraceId.traceKey -> traceId )
  }
}
```

But with that approach the Headers are attached to the Result and the Request is not touched I think.

In the Controller I would like to do something like

```
val traceId = traceIdfromReuest(request)
```

Is there a way to modifiy the RequestHeader for every incoming request to add an traceId-Header **before** the Controller gets it?
I already had a look at *Interceptors* http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaInterceptors but I found no lead how to manipulate the request header there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should construct a new `RequestHeader` from `rh`

```
val rhWithTraceId = rh....
```

for example:

```
val rhWithTraceId = rh.copy(tags = rh.tags + ("traceId" -> traceId))
```

and then you can all the next function with it

```
next(rhWithTraceId)
```

In your controller, you can then access the traceId from

```
request.tags.get("traceId")
```

Another solution would be to use [`ActionBuilder`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaActionsComposition%20ActionBuilder).

Comment: Added some clarification to the solution. Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 3):

As stated by @Yann Simon the easiest solution is to use **tags** instead of modifying the **http-headers** within the Request.

If you really want to modify the http-header within the RequestHeader you can do the following:

```
oldHeader.copy(
  headers =
    new Headers{
      val data : Seq[(String, Seq[String])]  = 
         oldHeader.headers.toMap.toSeq ++ additionalKeys.mapValues(Seq(_))
    }
)
```

The important part to keep in mind is, that if you want to modify the data in the RequestHeader within a filter it all boils down to the parameter given to the method with the signature `(RequestHeader) => Result` mostly called **next** in the examples.

```
object AddTraceIdFilter extends Filter  {
  override def apply(next: (RequestHeader) => Result)(rh: RequestHeader): Result = {

    val traceId = TraceId.fromRequestHeader(rh) getOrElse addAnTraceId
    next(
      rh.copy(tags = tags + ("traceId" -> traceId)) // <- Headers modified here will be readable from Reuest and the next filters
    ).withHeaders( "traceId" -> traceId ) // <- This just sets the httpHeaders for the Result given to the User after the filter has been applied, the values can not be read from within a controller
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First off I'd like to answer this question directly, and for the Java folks:

This is how you can use a filter to manipulate request headers before they touch the controller:

```
class TracingFilterAction extends Action<TracingFilter> {

    @Override
    public Promise<SimpleResult> call(Context ctx) throws Throwable {

        ctx.request().headers().put(key, value)
```

Since you asked a question about "tracing" a request, I felt the urge to share my LoggingFilter.

For the Play Framework Java community, I have developed an excellent LoggingFilter that will log the full request, headers & payload.

For the Scala community, it should still work for you, but you will have to live with some extra Java code in your Scala project :(

Usage

This will enable request logging at a class level

```
@LoggingFilter
public final class MyController extends Controller {   

}
```

This will enable request logging at a method level

```
@LoggingFilter
public Result index() {
    ...
}
```

Here is the implementation for 2.2.x (and possibly 2.2.3)

---

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

import play.Logger;
import play.Logger.ALogger;
import play.libs.F.Function0;
import play.libs.F.Promise;
import play.mvc.Action;
import play.mvc.Http.Context;
import play.mvc.Http.Request;
import play.mvc.SimpleResult;
import play.mvc.With;

@With(LoggingFilterAction.class)
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface LoggingFilter {

}

class LoggingFilterAction extends Action<LoggingFilter> {

    private static final String NOTIFICATION_PREFIX = "* ";
    private static final String REQUEST_PREFIX = "> ";
    private static final String RESPONSE_PREFIX = "< ";

    private final ALogger logger = Logger.of(getClass());
    private final AtomicLong _id = new AtomicLong(0);
    private final String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    @Override
    public Promise<SimpleResult> call(Context ctx) throws Throwable {
        long id = _id.incrementAndGet();
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        printRequestLine(b, id, ctx.request().method(), ctx.request().uri());
        printRequestHeaders(b, id, REQUEST_PREFIX, ctx.request().headers());
        String requestContent = contentAsString(ctx.request(), b);
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(requestContent)) {
            b.append(requestContent);
        }
        b.append(newLine);
        final SimpleResult result = delegate.call(ctx).get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        printResponseLine(b, id, getStatus(result));
        printResponseHeaders(b, id, RESPONSE_PREFIX, headers(result));
        String responseContent = contentAsString(result);
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(responseContent)) {
            b.append(responseContent);
        }
        b.append(newLine);
        logger.debug(b.toString());

        return Promise.promise(new Function0<SimpleResult>() {
            public SimpleResult apply() throws Throwable {
                return result;
            }
        });
    }

    private String header(String header, SimpleResult result) {
        return play.core.j.JavaResultExtractor.getHeaders(result).get(header);
    }

    private String charset(SimpleResult result) {
        String h = header("Content-Type", result);
        if (h == null) return null;
        if (h.contains("; charset=")) {
            return h.substring(h.indexOf("; charset=") + 10, h.length()).trim();
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private byte[] contentAsBytes(SimpleResult result) {
        return play.core.j.JavaResultExtractor.getBody(result);
    }

    private String contentAsString(Request request, StringBuilder b) {
        try {
            if (request.body() == null) {
                return "request has no body";
            }
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            return "request has no body";
        }
        if (request.body().asText() != null) {
            logger.debug("getting request body as text");
            return request.body().asText();
        }
        if (request.body().asRaw() != null) {
            logger.debug("getting request body as raw");
            try {
                return new String(request.body().asRaw().asBytes(), "utf-8");
            }
            catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        if (request.body().asJson() != null) {
            logger.debug("getting request body as json");
            return request.body().asJson().toString();
        }
        if (request.body().asFormUrlEncoded() != null) {
            logger.debug("getting request body as as formUrlEncoded");
            return toString(request.body().asFormUrlEncoded());
        }
        if (request.body().asMultipartFormData() != null) {
            logger.debug("getting request body as multipartFormData");
            return request.body().asMultipartFormData().toString();
        }
        if (request.body().asXml() != null) {
            logger.debug("getting request body as xml");
            return request.body().asXml().toString();
        }
        logger.debug("getting request body as default");
        return request.body().toString();
    }

    private String toString(Map<String, String[]> data) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> e : data.entrySet()) {
            String[] val = e.getValue();
            String key = e.getKey();
            if (sb.length() > 0) {
                sb.append("&");
            }
            try {
                sb.append(key).append("=").append(URLEncoder.encode(val[0], "utf-8"));
            }
            catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e1);
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private String contentAsString(SimpleResult result) {
        try {
            String charset = charset(result);
            if (charset == null) {
                charset = "utf-8";
            }
            return new String(contentAsBytes(result), charset);
        }
        catch (RuntimeException e) {
            throw e;
        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            throw new RuntimeException(t);
        }
    }

    private Map<String, String> headers(SimpleResult result) {
        return play.core.j.JavaResultExtractor.getHeaders(result);
    }

    private int getStatus(SimpleResult result) {
        return result.getWrappedSimpleResult().header().status();
    }

    private StringBuilder prefixId(StringBuilder b, long id) {
        b.append(Long.toString(id)).append(" ");
        return b;
    }

    private void printRequestLine(StringBuilder b, long id, String method, String uri) {
        prefixId(b, id).append(NOTIFICATION_PREFIX)
                .append("LoggingFilter - Request received on thread ")
                .append(Thread.currentThread().getName()).append("\n");
        prefixId(b, id).append(REQUEST_PREFIX).append(method).append(" ").append(uri).append("\n");
    }

    private void printResponseLine(StringBuilder b, long id, int status) {
        prefixId(b, id).append(NOTIFICATION_PREFIX)
                .append("LoggingFilter - Response received on thread ")
                .append(Thread.currentThread().getName()).append("\n");
        prefixId(b, id).append(RESPONSE_PREFIX).append(Integer.toString(status)).append("\n");
    }

    private void printResponseHeaders(StringBuilder b, long id, final String prefix,
            Map<String, String> headers) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : headers.entrySet()) {
            String val = e.getValue();
            String header = e.getKey();
            printPrefixedHeader(b, id, prefix, header, new String[] { val });
        }

    }

    private void printRequestHeaders(StringBuilder b, long id, final String prefix,
            Map<String, String[]> headers) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> e : headers.entrySet()) {
            String[] val = e.getValue();
            String header = e.getKey();
            printPrefixedHeader(b, id, prefix, header, val);
        }
    }

    private void printPrefixedHeader(StringBuilder b, long id, final String prefix, String header,
            String[] val) {
        if (val.length == 1) {
            prefixId(b, id).append(prefix).append(header).append(": ").append(val[0]).append("\n");
        }
        else {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            boolean add = false;
            for (Object s : val) {
                if (add) {
                    sb.append(',');
                }
                add = true;
                sb.append(s);
            }
            prefixId(b, id).append(prefix).append(header).append(": ").append(sb.toString())
                    .append("\n");
        }
    }

}
```

---

It should be a trivial exercise to add the ability to disable the logging based on reading a boolean config property.

Then in production/staging/whatever mode you can disable the LoggingFilter easily.

Cheers!